# How to get results from javascript in .NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

after long surfing via google I hope somebody can give good answer.

Here I have some javascript with I get in .NET C#

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var itemMap = new Array();
itemMap[0] = {
pid: "20466846",
sku: 13897265,
sDesc: "XSMALL",
sId: "101979",
cDesc: "Black",
cId: "1203740",
avail: "IN_STOCK",
price: "$4.99",
jdaStyle: "60016655"
```

};

How can I get results from this string in .NET that I can work with it?

I tried to use JINT (http://jint.codeplex.com/) but when I run script it's return for me type of object and I can not do anything with that...

I need with out some changes in javascript source get data. It's not JSON obj so I can not parse it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MVC or classic ASP.NET?

Comment: I am using MVC              .

Comment: Look at the answers and check the right one to close this question.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an appropriately formed JSON object stored in the clip board (which I'm guessing is the transport that you'll be using to send to your back-end), you can create an object via *Paste Special* under the edit menu that will generate the appropriate class in .NET to hold that object, e.g.

[image]

*This also works for XML objects.*

Comment: Thank it's good for the future, but not what I need.
I have just simple javascript text from server response, now I need with out some changing in source ( javascipt) get data from it.

It's not json, so it's would works.

Answer (score 1):

You can save these values into hidden fields

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hiddenField1 = document.getElementById('hiddenField1');
    hiddenField1.value = ???;
</script>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenField1" Value="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

and in codebehind file you can access the hidden field by

```
hiddenField1.Value;
```

Comment: That's also what I do when I'm not using json, post or query strings.